# Grails 3.2.9 with Oracle 12c Identity Column issues with groovy.Sql.executeInsert's with no id specified

Tags: oracle, hibernate, grails

Has anyone successfully migrated an app from Grails 2 to Grails 3 where backend is Oracle and you dropped to groovy.Sql to do inserts for performance reasons.

I have the Grails 2 (hibernate 4) app live against Oracle 12c where I use id mapping generator ‘sequence’ and pre-insert Oracle Trigger.

I’ve tried the same approach on Grails 3 (hibernate 5) and I get errors like “Found 1 parameter placeholders but supplied with 0 parameters” (always off-by 1), when using executeINSERT() without the id field specified (which is the way it used to work in grails 2).

The CRUD works ok, however.

I have tried generator ‘sequence-identity’ but this doesn’t change the table create id to NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY instead of NOT NULL, which is what I was expecting it to do (though the grails docs don't say this explicitly). [Oracle doc link](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/identity-columns-in-oracle-12cr1)

I’ve tried dropping back to hibernate 4 but still have the problem.

Any thoughts, please before I officially go mad?

Comment: If Oracle is going to generate the id, maybe you can remove the mapping and see what happens. The default behavior is id generation in db.

Comment: Elias, I tried removing the generator but still the same problem. Thanks for the thought though